# How can I keep SSH keys passwords in KDE wallet?

Tags: ssh, kde, kubuntu, kde-plasma-5

Kubuntu 18.04 KDE Plasma 5.12.7

I'm trying to keep my SSH password in KDE wallet. I'm adding an SSH key by ssh-add command and specifying a password but the system asks me for a password each time after system rebooted. I've tried many ways but no results.

Is there a special way to configure keeping SSH passwords for KDE wallet?

Comment: You didn't specify this in your question, so I'll just ask: have you tried the [archlinux wiki guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE_Wallet#Using_the_KDE_Wallet_to_store_ssh_key_passphrases)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried [this](https://github.com/jlesquembre/blog/blob/master/posts/using-the-kde-wallet-to-store-ssh-keys-with-passphrases.rst) tutorial in the past and got the work done

The first step is to install this package ksshaskpass. Find more about it on the [github](https://github.com/KDE/ksshaskpass) page. For example you can use the next command to install this package:

```
apt-get install ksshaskpass
```

The second step is to create a script as stated in the path mentioned. This will run the command when KDE starts. You can create the script with any text editor You are familiar.

The third step is to make the script You created in the second step, executable. Just run the command inside the folder, where the script You have created is, or provide the accurate path.

Then, the github author is recommending to stop the ssh agent when KDE is shutdown. Follow those recommendations as well. Again as step 2, You will need to use a text editor to create that script on the mentioned folder.

Finally if You want to remove the package and again input your pass every time, you can follow up the steps mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374729/how-to-not-use-ksshaskpass-with-ssh).

Comment: @Pavel Prischepa You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As this answer is somehow outdated but search engines show it, I want to refer to this thread: [How do I set up KDE, KWallet and ssh so I'm not asked to enter my ssh passphrase?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/724894/584379). It's more up to date and shows different approaches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).